# htaccess, symbolic child from parent folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I have add-on domains on my cpanel account pointing to, for example:

> example.com -> /sites/example/live

I would like to be able to access /sites/example/development when example.com/development is loaded:

> example.com/development -> /sites/example/development

I can get this to work using rewrites, but I can't access, for instance:

> example.com/development/images/img.png -> /sites/example/development/images/img.png

How can I get this to work?